# How to make responsive canvas inside a container?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a responsive container and want my canvas to change it's size according to canvas-container.

```
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <div class="canvas-toolbar"></div>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="840" height="480"></canvas>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let canvasContainer = document.querySelector(".canvas-container");
    let canvasToolbaar = document.querySelector(".canvas-toolbar");
    let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    let width;
    let height;
    width = canvasContainer.clientWidth ;
    height = canvasContainer.clientHeight - canvasToolbaar.clientHeight;
    canvas.setWidth(width);
    canvas.setHeight(height);


    function reportWindowSize() {
        width = canvasContainer.clientWidth;
        height = canvasContainer.clientHeight - canvasToolbaar.clientHeight;
        canvas.setHeight(height);
        canvas.setWidth(width);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize);
```

First I set width and height normally and then I am changing it during window resize.

Answer (score -1):

You can give % as a width for canvas, so it is going to change according to .canvas-container. how much `#canvas` going to cover inside the `.canvas-container`. Assume,

```
.canvas-container {
    width: 1000px;
}

#canvas {
    width: 84%; 
}
```

Comment: If I give the width using CSS , the canvas drawings get blurred